# Accumulo 1.5.1 - Cloudera CDH4.5 - TServer Unable to use port 9999

Tags: hadoop, accumulo, cloudera-cdh

Accumulo Instance Fails to Start with the following error - Any help would be appreciated

```
2014-06-13 14:48:51,682 [util.TServerUtils] INFO : Unable to use port 9999, retrying. (Thread Name = Master Client Service Handler)
2014-06-13 14:48:51,933 [util.TServerUtils] INFO : Unable to use port 9999, retrying. (Thread Name = Master Client Service Handler)
2014-06-13 14:48:52,183 [util.TServerUtils] INFO : Unable to use port 9999, retrying. (Thread Name = Master Client Service Handler)
2014-06-13 14:48:52,434 [util.TServerUtils] INFO : Unable to use port 9999, retrying. (Thread Name = Master Client Service Handler)
2014-06-13 14:48:52,684 [util.TServerUtils] INFO : Unable to use port 9999, retrying. (Thread Name = Master Client Service Handler)
2014-06-13 14:48:52,935 [util.TServerUtils] INFO : Unable to use port 9999, retrying. (Thread Name = Master Client Service Handler)
2014-06-13 14:48:53,185 [master.Master] ERROR: Unexpected exception, exiting
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to find a listen port
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.util.TServerUtils.startServer(TServerUtils.java:125)
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.master.Master.run(Master.java:2178)
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.master.Master.main(Master.java:2306)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.accumulo.start.Main$1.run(Main.java:103)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried modifying the port to 9995 using

```
 <property>  
    <name>master.port.client</name>  
    <value>9995</value>  
  </property>
```

in accumulo-site.xml

but fails with the same error !!!

So cross checked on all the ports used by the cluster - cloudera manager -- 9999 & and other series in the same used by cloudera manager -  Cloudera Manager Activity Monitor

Modified to a port number outside the series 9999 and yes the server is up and running..

Comment: Don't add details in an answer, but edit your original question.